# Advanced High Frequency Training

Tags: training, bodyweight-exercises, routine, bodyweight, functional-strength

I've been working on body weight training for just over a year now.  After the initial beginner routine, full body/3 day per week, I went to a 2 day split/4 days per week, and to a 3 day split/9 days per 2 weeks.  Now I'm looking to go back to a 4-5 day per week full body routine.  This came after I realized how much stronger and faster my core became after incorporating core/ab exercises into every workout.  I'm looking at incorporating super sets as much as possible.  Agonistic, antagonistic, and non-competitive.

My question is more looking for suggestions as far as how many exercises per muscle group per day, as well as appropriate volume.

Currently I'm doing about 4-6 sets of about 3-5 reps on difficult movements, and around 4-6 sets of 10-45 seconds for static holds.  Any other recommendations from experience is welcome to.

Answer (score 1):

**My question is more looking for suggestions as far as how many exercises per muscle group per day?**

Probably about 2 - 3 exercises, but really, its not about the number of exercise. It should be the **amount of volume done**(sets and reps done) on that day.

As for your last question, I don't have any experience in calisthenics. You may want to consider looking up on other calisthenics users, such as [fortress](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheF0rtress?gl=SG&hl=en-GB), [barstarzz](https://www.youtube.com/user/OfficialBarstarzz).

You may also want to define difficult movements. Do you mean something like planche push up, human flag?

Comment: Planche Pushups, I do clutch flags working my way to human flags, uneven/self supported one arm Pushups.  I even do full clean pull-ups (body straight, slow, no kipping, chin over the bar) and will start working towards one arm pull-ups.  That's just a small amount.  I'm also trying to develop some other specialty moves like front and back levers.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, these 2 - 3 exercise should be used to build muscle / lose fat depending on your goal. So the difficult ones can be done either on your off days or before / after your main workout.